# Group nodes by terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

How do you group a list of nodes by the taxonomy term?

e.g.

```
Term 1 
--- Node 1
--- Node 3
--- Node 7

Term 2
--- Node 6
--- Node 9
--- Node 12
```

I have tried creating a view with "Node" and "Taxonomy Term" as fields. I then enabled grouping, and grouped by the taxonomy term. Doing this outputs the following:

```
Term 1 
--- Node 1
Term 1
--- Node 3
Term 1 
--- Node 7   
Term 2
--- Node 6
Term 2
--- Node 9
Term 2
--- Node 12
```

There is a Drupal 6 [tutorial here](http://tiger-fish.com/blog/drupal-6-grouping-and-theming-nodes-under-taxonomy-single-page) that explains how to fix it, but it doesn't work under Drupal 7.

It seems like such a simple task, yet after many days of trying, I can't get it to work! I've found many threads of people asking the question, but no solutions (at lease a solution which doesn't involve installing taxonews).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your view add two fields:
- Node title
- Taxonomy Term

You are right up to here.

Now:

- Set the "Taxonomy Term" field to "Exclude from display"
- Select your views' format as unformatted list; use "Edit settings" for the format
- Set "Grouping Field" as "Taxonomy Term"

For details, view my views' export data in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/T6wdBnrL).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have followed your instructions and pasted in your views export data. But I still get it like the second example (where there term field is repeated for each node and not just displayed once [for the group of nodes that belong to that term]). Any help would be great as this is driving me crazy!

Comment: The repeated Term is due to field selection, You need to open your Term field in edit mode and check the option box against `Exclude from display`. This will hide the term from view.

Comment: But if I hide the term, then the list of nodes doesn't have a heading, so you cannot tell which nodes belong to which term. Isn't there a way to make the term appear just once (like in the first example I posted in my opening post (in the grey box)).

Comment: After hiding the Term, you need to focus on Views' Format. Click on Settings against Format. Then Set the Grouping Field as Taxonomy Term

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried what you have suggested, but the results still appear with the taxonomy term repeated for each field. I also tried your paste bin code, but same results. Here is my view exported to paste bin: http://pastebin.com/KNdGYyA8 I don't know if it will help with the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but it's working now! Here is the exported view, just in case it helps anyone: http://pastebin.com/nYn4R97a

Comment: ANy way to add a class or change the element type of the "Grouping field". I have this working exactly as mentioned but can't seem to make my grouping field anything other than an h3

Answer (score -3):

I resolved the problem of duplicated grouping fields :D

So, for people who have the same problem, just disable your module Themer and it's done !

Hope it helps.